# Android Google Map not showing

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I've followed [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) for creating a map in an Android application, but I don't know why but when I launch the application, i can't see the map, here's exactly what I get: 
 Check the image [Image1](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=631586Screenshot20140102141754.png)

Like I said, I followed exactly the tutorial, but just in case... here's my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
   }
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest File (xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Poox2.andtestmap4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Poox2.andtestmap4.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDmVLuYyZce...-Rest of the API key -"/>
       </application>

    </manifest>
```

Thank you for you answers so far, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

to

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Make sure you have enabled maps for android in the google api console. Make sure the api key in the manifest is right. Make sure you have referenced google play services library project in your android map project.

Also it is better to test on a real device.

Comment: @user3072183 also test it on a device that has google play services apk

Comment: I'm testing it in Samsung Galaxy tab2, so I don't think that this is the problem. As for the first answer, I checked the API key, Maps for Android checked, Library already added, still not working.

Comment: @user3072183 you will use `SupportMapFramgent` for api level 11 and below in which case you extend `FragmentActivity`. that is not yur case hence the first suggestion is right. You can refer the docs for that. Generate a new key and try again

Comment: @user3072183 recreate the api key and try again

Answer (score 0):

try to generate the api key by going to [Google API console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key) and even try to add Google play services library..

```
Select Window > Android SDK Manager or run android at the command line.
Scroll to the bottom of the package list and select Extras > Google Play services. The Google Play services SDK is downloaded to your computer and installed in your Android SDK environment at <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/

Add the Google Play Services project into your Eclipse workspace.

Click File -> Import..., select Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace
Browse to and select <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

To add the dependency to Google Play Services into your project

Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: I did, i just didn't posted it here don't worry :) thanks anyway :)

Comment: I've recrated another project with another API key, i have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I had a map display problem and it turned out that my solution to uninstall and reinstall the application on the device (not just install over top of it).  I can't find the SO that helped me, but it looked like the API key or something else was being cached on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've find the problem, it was with the Package name in Google Console... when I generated the API key, the SHA1 key was correct, when I added the package name, the name was wrong that's why the map wasn't showing up. Thank you so much for you help guys I really appreceate it :).

Answer (score 0):

Your have to use Fragment activity

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    double lati;
    double long;
    boolean flag = false;
    // private LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapptry);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                 }
  }
```

The XML for the map is here

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Do do this also

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Before you do this Right click project->properties->buildpath->java build path -> libraries .. then click on add external jars
Then add the required jar

If you API key is wrong then also it shows only a white screen